# Getting error when I create variable outside the render method

Tags: reactjs, components

Why this does not work outside the render method

```
 class MyComponentClass extends React.Component{
        const n = Math.floor(Math.random()* 10 + 1);
        render(){
            return <h1>The number is {n}</h1>
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponentClass/>,document.getElementById("app"));
```

But it works inside?

```
 class MyComponentClass extends React.Component{
        render(){
            const n = Math.floor(Math.random()* 10 + 1);
            return <h1>The number is {n}</h1>
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponentClass/>,document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: why do you want to initialize const outside render ?

Comment: Just trying to understand why this is a problem :) @SakhiMansoor

Comment: 1) Class properties aren't standard ES yet. 2) Class properties do not have declarators.

Comment: By the way, your second method is the same as the first one. Probably you wanted to move the assignment in the render method.

Comment: Oh my bad. Fixed! @devserkan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the first one you are defining a class property with a new proposal: `class-fields` You can't use `const` there. Try like this:

```
n = Math.floor(Math.random()* 10 + 1);
```

Then you can reach it via:

```
this.n
```

I don't know why this answer downvoted but with a proper setup, `class-fields` plugin like Babel, for example, we can use this.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  render() {
    return <div>{this.n}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This is not different other than initializing the property in the constructor without using `class-fields` proposal.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );
    this.n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>{this.n}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```